# finding all matches and returning values from array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a')
sel[0] == // ELEMENT WITH div.bottom ul li a.box
sel[1] == // ELEMENT WITH div.head ul li a.box

var list = [
    {css: 'a span', val:'1st'},
    {css: 'div.bottom ul a', val:'2nd'},
    {css: 'div.head li > a.box', val:'3rd'},
    {css: 'div.head li a', val:'4th'}
]

//desired result 
"sel[0] matches 2nd"
"sel[1] matches 3rd,4th"
```

I'm trying to find all css selectorAll matches from a list.
I know I can use nested for loop and loop through both selectors and list in this way

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (sel[0].matches(list[i].css)) {
      console.log(list[i].val);
    }
  }
```

but trying to find better solution without using nested for loop.
How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `filter()` method to get all matching elements of an array.

```
sel.forEach((el, i) => {
    let matches = list.filter(item => el.matches(item.css));
    if (matches.length > 0) {
        console.log(`sel[${i}] matches ${matches.map(item => item.val).join(',')}`);
    }
}
```